# Reading local files from file path in javascript

Tags: javascript, file

I have been struggling with reading local files **from the file path** in `javascript`. I have tried `XMLHttpRequest` to no avail.

```
function readFile(file) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
      if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
        var text = rawFile.responseText;
        document.write(text);
      }
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}

window.onload = function() {
  readFile("text.txt");
}
```

I have also tried `FileReader` but the way I understand it is that it doesn't read files from a string file path; or how can I create a `File` object to use in `FileReader`. I also don't want to use `node fs module`. Could anyone help out on the best and surest way to read local files **from the file path**? THANKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Security restrictions in most browsers make this impossible.

Webpages are not allowed to select files from the user's computer to make accessible to JavaScript. Only the user (e.g. via a file `<input>`) can do that.

Comment: ok thanks... is there a way I can create a `File` object or something of the sort without accessing local files to use in `FileReader`?

Comment: If you don't want to access local files with it … what do you want to access with it?

Comment: I could let's say test `FileReader` using `jasmine`

Comment: You'd probably need to mock the FileReader object entirely to do that.

Comment: how would I do that?

Comment: like is it possible to create like a `File` object and use `FileReader` to read it?

Comment: please help on how to do it